# MouseClickEvent for a UserControl doesn't fire when its Children are clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for my query but I am just a beginner in using `UserControl`:

Why do MouseClickEvent of a UserControl doesn't get inherited by the controls (e.g Labels) inside it?

To show you how I instantiate the UserControl inside a `flowLayoutPanel`:

```
        studentItemList[] listItem = new studentItemList[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < listItem.Length; i++)
        {
            listItem[i] = new studentItemList();
            listItem[0].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
            listItem[i].MouseDoubleClick += StudentPrev;
            listItem[i].StudentID = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);
            listItem[i].StudentName = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(1) + ", " + dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(2) + " " + dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(3);
            listItem[i].StudentEmail = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(4);
            listItem[i].StudentStatus = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(5);

            flowLayoutPanelStudents.Controls.Add(listItem[i]);
        }
```

**studentItemList.cs:**

```
 public partial class studentItemList : UserControl
{
    public studentItemList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _studID, _studName, _studEmail, _status;

    public string StudentID
    {
        get { return _studID; }
        set { _studID = value; studentNo.Text = value; }
    }
    public string StudentName
    {
        get { return _studName; }
        set { _studName = value; studentName.Text = value; }
    }

    private void studentNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }




    public string StudentEmail
    {
        get { return _studEmail; }
        set { _studEmail = value; studentEmail.Text = value; }
    }

    public string StudentStatus
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { _status = value; status.Text = value; }
    }





    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

`Label.Autosize` is set to `true` and `DockStyles` are set to `Left`.

Although, the `MouseEvent` get's triggered when the parent Panel of the `UserControl` is clicked.

What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wire up all controls that may receive a click event.

If all controls in yout user control are added before the control is instantiated (e.g. design-time) then you can add event handlers in the user control's constructor.
If the user control has controls added/removed at run-time then you'll need to wire up `ControlAdded` and `ControlRemoved` events to wire/unwire events.